# How to play 2 audio simultaneously in java?

Tags: java, javasound

Basic idea is to combine images, voice and background music to create a single movie. I am able to do the same with images and voice audio (single audio) but now i want to add 2 audio files for the same.

Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this solution which worked for me on Ubuntu 11.10

http://www.jsresources.org/examples/AudioConcat.html

with source code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the two sound clips into memory as a single unit, then play them.

Refer to http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=1948.0 for a great example of how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply....but too much noise.....not able to hear the sound at all...if you have a working sample please send...i am working on ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: I did the same thing locally, using Java 7 on a Windows 7 32-bit machine with my own clips and it seems to work as expected. Perhaps your source files don't play well together?

Comment: Hey i tried with a single audio file still same result m i doing some thing wrong in the code....here the code

Comment: It could also be your sound drivers, Java does not play well with all sound drivers, especially "generic" drivers.

Comment: Ok buddy will try with diiferent OS.